# Examples of Direct Summands of Polynomial Rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I know the coordinate rings of Veronese surfaces are direct summands of polynomial rings, and also in general rings of invariants $S^G$ of a group (maybe it needs to be linearly reductive).

Are there any other "common" examples of direct summands of polynomial rings?

Also, do we have explicit descriptions for certain rings of invariants? For example, the Veronese surfaces are rings of invariants under action of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. Do we have a "nice" description for the rings of invariants of groups such as $SL_n$ (possibly in low dimension)?

Thanks!

Comment: I assume you mean $S=R\oplus M$ as $R$-modules where $S$ is a polynomial ring. Veronese subrings are a kind of monomial algebra (affine semigroup ring), which are also normal. In fact, this suffices for an affine semigroup ring to be a direct summand of a polynomial ring by a theorem of Hochster, i.e. if $R=K[A]$ is an affine semigroup ring which is normal, $R$ is a direct summand of a polynomial ring as an $R$-module.

Comment: An affine semigroup ring is normal precisely when the affine semigroup is an intersection of half-spaces with the lattice $\mathbb{Z}^n$, which is a combinatorial/topological criterion, see for example "Normal Semigroup Rings" by Bruns.